How to add entry to RMB to open a file with a specific program
I am trying to add Emacs in Windows 10 to a context menu (RMB), so that I right-click on a file and have an option to open a file in Emacs. I understand there exists "Open With" but in my case this doesn't work due to a little more complicated case.
Here's the reason: I run EmacsClient instead of Emacs, which utilises a server (service) in background. Consequently, core mods are loaded at startup and residue in memory to speed up opening application and only front user settings are used to open a window. For this, I created a shortcut to run Emacs as follows
"C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-29.4\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -c -a ""

If I add EmacsClinet in Open With, it only executes emacsclientw.exe without additional options -c and -a "", which are important.
I tried following some suggestions using Windows registry but they don't t work. Here's what I did so far

Added a new key in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ called Emacs and set its (Defalut) value to Open with &Emacs
Added an additional value Icon and set its value to a path to the existing icon: C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-29.4\bin\runemacs.exe
Added a new key in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Emacs called command and set its (Default) value to "C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-29.4\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -c -a ""
I closed regedit and restarted Windows Explorer.

At this point, I expected to have an additional entry under RMB, such as Open With EmacsClient, but it's not there. I did also restart a computer, but this also did not help. I read if entries in registry are incorrect, Windows does not show it under RMB. Could someone help what I am doing wrong? Thanks

You are limiting the menu to only directories, and you right-click a folder, right?

No, I am trying to right-click on a file and open it with EmacsClient. Sorry if it was not clear in the question.

Your registry key is only for directories. If you want files, use HK_CR\* (the top one) instead, to match against any file extension.

@LPChip Hey. It's working now :) I'll upvote and accept your answer if you create one. Just one thing though, I had to add %V at the end in order to open files. Otherwise, it would only open the application with empty window. I found that in another key for VSCode. Regardless, thanks for your help!

The registry key you provided is for directories.
For files, you use its extension or the * to match any extension, which is what you want.
You mentioned you needed to add %V too so it knows what file you clicked. I thought %1 would also work, and not sure what %V stands for.

Hello again. I feel like I should mentioned the following. It turns out that "%1" argument does not always work for some reason and for files with some extensions. I found a list of special variables here and after replacing "%1" with "%0", it works now. I don't know why  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

%1 is the first parameter, %0 is all parameters. If you don't quote the %1, and you have a file in a folder with spaces, then it will be treated as multiple parameters, but if you use "%1" then it is treated as one parameter instead. %0 however will still parse everything but without the quotes as multiple parameters, and then it is up to the executable to be not picky about the spaces, so it will sometimes work, some other times it won't. It may also be that you actually have to double quote the %1, so it becomes ""%1"" so that it actually sends the " along with the %1.

"%1" works. I didn't understand the difference between %0 and %1 from the link and did not realise those should be between quotation marks. Seems like Emacs parses  spaces as parts of a path. I have more questions about it but I'll make another post. Thanks.
